# Recursion and variable values

Tags: c#, .net, recursion

I have a recursive method which is simplified below:

```
private List<string> data;
public string Method1()
{
    data = new List<string>();

    //When Method 1 gets called first time there is a problem
    //When Method 1 gets called from Method2 problem is fixed
    if (problem)
    {
        data.Add("prob");
    }

    if(data.Count > 0)
    {
        return Method2()
    }
    else
    {
        return string.Empty();
    }
}

private string Method2()
{
    return Method1();
}
```

When Method1 gets called from Method2 am I right thinking that the `data` variable is reinitialized wiping out what was previously in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `Method1` you are creating new `List<string>` so old `data` variable value becomes inaccessible (will be garbage collected).

To avoid it, you have to initialize `data` somewhere outside `Method1` e.g. in constructor.

Comment: Thought so. Have a weird bug in that when Method1 gets called from Method2 it still says there a problem and wondered if it was because there was originally data in the List but I was sure that the recursion would have wiped it out.